# Command 'git show someLightWeightTag' shows too much information about commit

Tags: git

I've created a lightweight tag using 'git tag light' and tried to display it with 'git show light'. On page git-scm.com and everywhere else it's said that i should only get basic information however I get full information with diffs between my files. Where is the problem?

Comment: Could you link the pages where you got that information?

Comment: `git show --help`: For tags, it shows the tag message and the referenced objects.

Comment: Actually, light tags are just pointers to commit. So there is nothing to show.